# Issue with late binding

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have a macro launched from Excel to control a Word document.

In order to prevent issues with references (**Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library** or **Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library** for example) I use late binding in the main macro :

```
Public appWord as Object
Sub MainSub()
 Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
 If appWord Is Nothing Then
     Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 End If
 'Create temp file'
 '...'
 'Open temp file = strTempWordFile'
 Set docWord = appWord.Documents.Open(strTempWordFile)
 'Launch function to search text and remove it from the word document
 SearchAndRemove rgCell2.Text, docWord
End Sub
```

Here is an extract of the function (in another module)

```
Sub SearchAndRemove(ByVal strSearchWord As String, ByRef docWord As Word.Document)
   Set selWordSelection = appWord.Selection 'That works
   selWordSelection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory   'line with issue
   'do the search and remove'
End Sub
```

If the Sub is called via declaring docWord as Word.Document (which requires reference to **Microsoft Word 1X.0 Library**, this line works OK :

```
selWordSelection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
```

If the Sub is called via declaring docWord as Object (which ***does not***  require reference to **Microsoft Word 1X.0 Library**, this line does not work anymore.

Comment: If you remove the library reference then `wdStory` is an unknown value, replace it with its true literal value (add a reference temporarily and ?wdStory in the immediate window to see what it is).  Adding `option explicit` to the top of your modules would highlight this error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the numerical equivalent then:

- Open the application in question (in your case `Word`)
- Open the VBE (Alt + F11)
- Open the Immediate window (Ctrl + G)
- Enter the keyword in the immediate window preceded by a ? (`?wdStory`)
- Use the number it returns in your code.

In this case you need to replace `wdStory` with the number `6`.
(and just read the middle line of @AlexK comment - *add a reference temporarily and ?wdStory in the immediate window to see what it is*)
Never thought of adding the referencing and using the immediate window in the current app.  I know I'd forget to remove it again though.